# Location of Souce code for Plugins on our local machine

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Where are the source code for plugins present in the gazebo source on our machines?
For example, what is the location of this file https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8479ce0c42565f05c6ad33bbcaaea0b72ab6f815/plugins/RandomVelocityPlugin.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12043/location-of-souce-code-for-plugins-on-our-local-machine/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

depending on how you installed gazebo:

a) If from source, then the file is where you downloaded the repository:

`/MyPath/gazebo/plugins/RandomVelocityPlugin.cc`

b) If from debian (`sudo apt-get install gazebo..`):

you can find **only** the header file by running `$ locate RandomVelocityPlugin.hh`, it should give you a path similar to:
`/usr/include/gazebo-5.1/gazebo/plugins/`

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2015-11-12**:
Thanks, I had found the header, but wasn't able to figure out why the source c++ file isn't there.
Is there any way I can add it to my source? OR In which folder can I try out writing new plugins?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2015-11-12**:
If you install from debian you don't get the source files, you need to download the repository. If you want to start writing plugins you do it differently. Check out the plugin tutorials: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=write_plugin